# Konva JS. Change Image position, rotate

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm adding an image.

```
circle = new Image ();
circle.src = '/img/logo.png';
circle.onload = function () {
     anyimage = new Konva.Image ({
          x: 150,
          y: 150,
          image: circle,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
     });
     layer.add (anyimage);
     stage.add (layer);
};
```

How to get and change the position and angle of this picture?
How to change these settings later. By events. For example, clicking on the buttons.
Method this.setX(),this.rotare(), this.x= not work for image obj.

Comment: live code
https://codepen.io/abramovks/pen/WXWRRq

Answer (score 3):

Solution. Need use anyimage obj. Not cirle.

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.3.0/konva.js"></script>
<button onclick='rotate_image()'>rotate_image</button> 
<button onclick='setPos_image()'>rotsetPos_imageate_image</button>
<div id="container"></div>

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
                  container: 'container',  // индификатор div контейнера
                  width: 500,
                  height: 500
            });

            var layer = new Konva.Layer();

           circle = new Image();
           circle.src = 'https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=caa07f7c7eb5b2788719c85cd6028d23&n=13'; 
            circle.onload = function() {
                anyimage = new Konva.Image({
                x: 10,
                y: 10,
                image: circle,
                width: 106,
                height: 118
              });

              layer.add(anyimage);
              stage.add(layer);
             };

function rotate_image(){
  anyimage.rotate(45);
              stage.draw();
              console.log('loaded');
}

function setPos_image(){
 //code for change x,y coord of 'circle' obj
  anyimage.setX(45);
              stage.draw();
              console.log('loaded');
}
```

Comment: Most times after you move or change a shape on the canvas that change is NOT automatically drawn for you. This is to allow you to reduce the number of costly redraws. In game dev they call this a back buffer technique. You get the layout of the back buffer as you need it, maybe moving 100 shapes, then you call a fast blit operation to copy that into the visible view. Konvajs is giving a closely similar capability - you move your shapes then finally call a stage,draw() when done.

Answer (score 0):

The position and size are as you have set in the new Konva.Image() call. Rotation is demonstrated in [this example](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/animations/Rotation.html) and below in the working snippet. Basically there is a rotation point set by the 'offset' property of the shape. By default this is at the top left of the image rectangle. You apply the shape's rotate() function setting the single parameter to the amount of degrees to rotate by, with rotation happening around the shapes offset(x,y) position.

See snippet below for a playpen.

*Note: I have raised a question with the author over the apparent unexpected behaviour that means when you change the offset position, intending to change the center of rotation, the shape is physically moved.*

```js
// Add a stage for the shapes
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 1600,
      height: 400
    });

// add a layer
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// add a rect to demonstrate rotation
var r = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 60,
        y: 30,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'red',
        opacity: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 0})
layer.add(r);  

// add a spot to mark the rotate pt
var c = new Konva.Circle({
      x: 45,
      y: 45,
      radius: 4,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4})
layer.add(c);  
stage.draw();

// event for plus & minus buttons
$('#plus').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   r.rotate(10)
   stage.draw();
})

$('#minus').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   r.rotate(-10)
   stage.draw();
})

// function to set rotate point and shape
function setPos(pos){

   r.setAttr('offsetX', pos.x);
   r.setAttr('offsetY', pos.y);
   c.position({
      x: r.x(),
      y: r.y()
    });
    c.moveToTop();
    sayPos();
      stage.draw();
}      


$('#ctr').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   setPos({x:25, y:25});
})

$('#topLeft').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   setPos({x:0, y:0});
})

$('#topRight').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   setPos({x:50, y:0});
})

$('#botCtr').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault()
   setPos({x:25, y:50});
})


function sayPos(){
  $('#info').html('Rotate pt=' + r.offsetX() + ", " + r.offsetY());
}

// call the setPos() and sayPos() funcs on load.
setPos({x:0, y:0});
sayPos();
```

```css
p
{
  padding: 4px;
  
}
#container
{
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
div
{
padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id='info1'></div>
<div id='info2'></div>

<div>Click row 1 buttons to set rotate pt and row 2 buttons to rotate by 10 degrees</div>
<div>
  <button id='topLeft'>Move rotate pt to top left</button>
  <button id='ctr'>Move rotate pt to center</button>
  <button id='topRight'>Move rotate pt to top right</button>
  <button id='botCtr'>Move rotate pt to bottom center</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id='plus'>+10</button>
  <button id='minus'>-10</button>
  <span id='info'>Info:</span>
</div>
  <div id="container"></div>
            
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: this method not work with image object. No problem with polygon. But image not have rotate,setpos,getX,setX and other method. Image here- JS HtmlObj. Polygon - JS ObjectObject.

I try change cirle.x=123. Not work. Try circle.style.css.margin|top|other - not work.

Comment: If you know how to solve the problem. Please write, as in my example, change the coordinate of the image and rotate it to some angle.

Comment: In the image load event, after the anyimage is loaded to the stage, rotate it like **anyimage.rotate(45);** followed by stage.draw().  Looks like a Konva image roatate point is topleft by default, same as rect. See live codepen https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/POgpdz

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain right away. I can turn when I create. The task is to change these settings later. By events. For example, clicking on the buttons. Has corrected the live code

Comment: In my task it is necessary that the picture repeats the movement of the object on the other canvas. For example with 'dragmove'. I define the position of the master object. But I can not translate its coordinates into a picture. But I'll do it without problems if I figure out how to change the parameters for example by clicking on the button)
circle2.on ('dragmove', function () {
x = circle2.getX ()
y = circle2.getY ());

Comment: Ohhh
stage.draw();
and anyimage, not circle obj. You are my hero! Thank you very very much!